# "producer cell line" vs. "host cell line" in biopharmacology

Tags: terminology, cell-culture, translation

I'm translating a text that describes the creation and testing of a cell line that produces a drug (a protein) and also procedures for creation and maintenance of cell banks.

Example sentence:

> Assessment of the morphology, viability, and cell concentration of the **producer cell line**

I wonder if I can use **host cell line** instead of **producer cell line**, or "host cell line" would mean "a line that has not yet been subjected to transformation using viral vectors" (a line that cannot yet produce the needed drug; a "pure" line). Just making sure.

Comment: What is uclear about my question? I'm asking whether the two expressions can be used synonymously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would lean towards staying with "producer cell line". In my mind, a host cell line is *hosting* something, like a virus, while a producer *produces* something. The non-transformed cell line would be the *parent* cell line.

On the other hand, "host cell line" also implies hosting the recombinant protein product that is later purified, so there's an argument to be made for either phrase. I still prefer *producer*, though, as I think it's more directly descriptive of what the cells are actually doing - *producing* the protein of interest.